# How to check if we are between 2 datetime objects right now?

Tags: java, jodatime, utc

I have an object that has as member a start datetime and end datetime

```
class MyObject {  
   DateTime start;  
   DateTime end;  

   public MyObject(String isoUtcStart, String isoUtcEnd) {
      this.start = new DateTime(isoUtcStart);  
      this.end = new DateTime(isoUtcEnd);  
   }  
}
```

What I want is to determine if we are right now in the range of these moments.
I am doing it as follows:

```
public boolean isWithinCurrentTime(MyObject o) {  
     DateTime now = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
     return (o.getStart().isBefore(now) || o.getStart().isEqual(now))
                    && (o.getEnd().isAfter(now) || o.getEnd().isEqual(now));  
}
```

This seems a bit overkill though. Is there a better way? I mean:

1. is there something that is like `isBeforeOrEqual`? Can't find such a method
2. Is there a difference with doing `o.getStart().isBeforeNow()`? Not sure if that is the same i.e. UTC comparison
3. Is moving to `long` comparisons (`getmillis`) a saner approach?

Comment: I don't think the isEqual() is necessary.  With the resolution of `datetime` objects, those cases are pretty much never going to happen.  You would only need to do that if you were constraining the current time to a certain time of day.

Comment: @Steve: May be I am missing your point but since the `start` contains hours and mins, wouldn't it be wrong to exclude the possibility that `now` is exactly the same hours and mins?

Comment: It contains more than that.  It goes down to millis at least.

Comment: This question was closed as duplicate to the other but in the other there is no explanation if UTC is being used or not

Comment: @Ole V.V.: Does it use UTC?

Comment: The way the `DateTime` objects are created in the top answer to the other question is using the default time zone (not UTC). But just use the `DateTime` objects that you have created in UTC instead. BTW Joda-Time has no problem comparing `DateTime` objects across time zones, so the comparison itself would work anyway.

Comment: @OleV.V. `has no problem comparing DateTime objects across time zones` I am confused here. My understanding is a `DateTime` has no timezone. A `LocalDateTime` only has timezone

Comment: It’s almost the other way around. A `LocalDateTime` hasn’t got any time zone, so doesn’t define a point on the timeline. `DateTime` has got a *UTC offset* (not a time zone) and does define a point in time.

Answer (score 1):

Use joda's [Interval](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class to represent `[start;end)` time interval. And then check if this time interval contain the specified instant.

```
Interval interval = new Interval(o.getStart(), o.getEnd());
interval.contains(DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC))
```

Or you can try using `interval.containsNow()` without passing `now` explicitly.

Comment: `containsNow` uses `UTC`?

Comment: You don’t need to care, @Jim. A `DateTime`, no matter if in UTC or not, uniquely defines a point in time, and Joda-Time correctly determines which comes before or after another one independently of time zone offsets.

Comment: @OleV.V.: When you say `uniquely defines a point in time` this implies a timescale/timeline that is common for all `DateTime` points. What is this timescale/timeline if not UTC?

Comment: I don’t know and we don’t need to care. My guess would be it’s implemented as milliseconds since the epoch. @Jim

Comment: Yes, `containsNow`  is actually a call to `contains` but with `DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis()` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is.

import Date classes java.util.Date

Make use of these methods

date1.after( date2 ) – It returns true is date1 comes after date2; else false.

date1.before( date2 ) – It returns true is date1 comes before date2; else false.

date1.compareTo( date2 )

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. JodaTime was asked about and offers an more elegant solution than `Date`. I discourage using this answer.